# Are Tortoise svn minor revisions compatible?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a branch checked out in Tortoise 1.4.2, edited it in 1.6.2 and now can't modify it on my old machine running 1.4.2. The latest version on the Tortoise website is 1.6.7. Are versions 1.6.x interoperable?  I'm stuck with version 1.6.2 on my new machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, a basic principle with SVN is that :

- When you have a working copy in 1.4.x and you use a 1.6.x tool to work on it, it'll automatically be converted to 1.6.x
- Which means you will not be able to work with your 1.4.x tool anymore

Between 1.6.x and 1.6.y, I've never seen any problem.

Comment: With my current setup, TortoiseSVN 1.6.8 works fine, but TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 can't check out projects from my repository, so compatibility isn't always guaranteed between patch releases.

Answer (score 0):

Tortoise SVNuses the Subversion libraries underneath, and the first two parts of Tortoise's version numbers match up with the version of the Subversion libraries, so Tortoise SVN versionion1.6.x will use the Subversion client libraries version 1.6.y.

The Subversion team often changes the working copy format between minor releases (1.5.x -> 1.6.x) but try hard not to break compatibility between patch releases (1.6.2 -> 1.6.3).  Newer versions can read old working copies, but only to immediately upgrade them.

So the answer to your question is "Yes".